# How do I disable the Windows 10 update prompt on an existing Windows 10 install?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-10-upgrade

I've got a number of stick PCs deployed for digital signage that currently run Windows 10.

About a week or so ago, Microsoft released a new update for Windows 10 that I'm getting prompted to install even after closing the prompt repeatedly.

A prompt opens up over the top of Internet Explorer running in kiosk mode, and therefore is interfering with my digital signs.

Is there a way to completely disable this prompt? Installing the update is not an option, because there isn't enough disk space available on the stick PCs to install the update.

Comment: any update? Does the tool in my answer works for you?

Answer (score 1):

There is no other official way to permanently block updates except the Troubleshooter from [KB3073930](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3073930).

But there is a nice 3rd party tool called [Windows Update MiniTool](http://www.wilderssecurity.com/threads/windows-update-minitool.380535/) which allows to select which updates can be installed and allows to block updates like you could in former Windows versions.

[image]

> An alternative to the standard Windows Update What you can do: • Check
>   for updates 
>  • Download updates
>  • Installing Updates
>  •
>   Deleting installed updates
>  • **Hiding unwanted updates**
>  • Get
>   direct links to the *.cab / *.Exe / *.Psf update files • View update
>   history
>  • Configure Automatic Updates
>  • This tool is like the
>   external powershell module PSWindowsUpdate, but much more advanced and
>   user-friendly features
>  • The tool relies and use same WU
>   infrastructure, all downloading are through WU it's not a
>   downloader

Try this tool to stop offering the update over and over again.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft released a troubleshooting package that lets you show/hide updates in Windows 10. Looks like they did this because of issues caused by Windows Update installing drivers, but you can use/abuse this for any kind of update it seems.

KB Article:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3073930